# Sidescroller game with libgdx / Box2D with moving floor instead of moving player

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'd like to write a sidescroller game with libgdx and Box2D.

But instead of the moving the player and the camera to the right, the player should stay at his position and the floor should move to the left. Crates should be placed randomly and move from the right to the left of the screen as well. In addition the player should also be able to move to the left and the right of the screen without the game stopping to scroll the level.

I have no problems with using libgdx or Box2d but I'm not sure what is the best way to achieve my goal. I'd like to use physics because I will also have some bouncing balls etc. in the game which should show a physically correct behaviour and should interact with the player.

I have some ideas how to solve my problem:

- Apply constant force or velocity to the floor and the crates which pushes them to the left and apply a counter force to the player so it stays at his position. When pushing the left or right button to move the player the counter force is slighty enhanced or decreased.
  *(As physic simulation is not 100% percent accurate I'd like to avoid this)*
- Move the position of the floor, player and crates but this would subvert the whole physics thing.
- Use physics for anything but the player and move him directly. Therefor I'd have to do any collission detection by myself

Unforunately I'm not happy with any of these solutions. Has anybody faced a similar problem or has any advice how to solve this problem in an elegant way?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just move the viewpoint along with the player?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to create two separate cameras: for player and for ground(floor).
Such way you will be able to move your "ground camera" as you want, the player will stay on his position. Then just don't move your player camera, move only the player `body` ,such way you will get effect of racetrack.

I use 4 cameras on my game (for ground, for player, for HUD and for background) it provides you lots of fixability and you can create cool scrolling effects.

Comment: Lifes, movement control buttons, coins count etc. Elements which doesn't move and always visible as a top layer.